# How can i stop a view from rendering after modelchange?

Tags: backbone.js

I have 2 models, one called profile and a collection of profiles called profilelist.

One view shows a list of the profiles, its called profileListView and when you click on a profile, it loads a new view, profileDetailsView, where you can edit its details.

Now when i change properties in this profileDetailsView of this profile and do a model.Change, the profileListView rerenders, because it obviously listens to its model.
The problem is the view rerenders but the URL stays the same, pointing to the detailsview of the profile i changed, which messes up the navigation of the site.

So i want to stop the automatic rerendering of the profileListView and then manually 'redirect' to the listview.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably *do* want the view to re-render, right? You just want the url to change too. So one option would be to have your router bind a handler on the model, and then have it update the URL - something like:

```
model.on('change', function(model) {
    var url = getTheCorrectUrl(model);
    router.navigate(url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro, actually i had to put it in the success of the model.save, otherwise it would reload the page before it would save the model and ultimately not save the model. Also I had to use router.saveLocation and not navigate since apparently the site works with an old version of BackBone (0.3.3)